# How do I make this slideDown/slideUp work properly with different classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn jQuery but I can't seem to figure out the following.

When the page loads, div 1 should be visible.
When I click on a menu button, div 1 should hide and the clicked div should replace it.

I would like div 1 to have a different class assigned to it (can this be done without CSS?) and have the 2 classes toggle when you select one from notactive to active.

How can this be done in jQuery?

https://jsfiddle.net/3kvfy4oa/

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='menu'>
    <ul id='List'>
        <li><a href="#content1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id='content'>
    <div id=content1 class="">
    <h1>Div 1</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div id=content2 class="disactivated">
    <h1>Div 2 </h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div id=content3 class="disactivated">
    <h1>Div 3</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#menu{
    width:150px;
    left:-180px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
div#menu ul li{
    margin-bottom: 1px;   
    position: relative;
    float : left; 
}
div#menu ul#List li a{
    width: 150px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #00293E;
    /*color: #ffffff;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

#content{
    left:50px;
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
}
.disactivated{
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        $(this)
          .slideDown('fast')
          .siblings("div:visible").slideUp('fast')
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery code, `$(this)` refers to the `a` element (the element on which you click), not your target div.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $(target)
        .slideDown('fast')
        .siblings("div:visible").slideUp('fast');
})
```

If you want to toggle `disactivated` class, chain it like this:

```
    $(target)
        .removeClass('disactivated')
        .slideDown('fast')
        .siblings("div:visible")
            .slideUp('fast')
            .addClass('disactivated');
```

Also, you might want to add `return false` to the end of your event handler when using click events on links. The final code should look like this:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $(target)
        .removeClass('disactivated')
        .slideDown('fast')
        .siblings("div:visible")
            .slideUp('fast')
            .addClass('disactivated');

    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful